# GROUP BY in subquery to get accurate ranking

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get the rank of a particular lap time of a specific track owned by a particular user.

There are multiple rows (laps) in this table for a specific user. So I'm trying to GROUP BY as seen in the subquery of FIND_IN_SET.

Right now MySQL (latest version) is complaining that my session_id,user_id,track_id,duration are not aggregated for the GROUP BY.

Which I don't understand why its complaining about this since the GROUP BY is in a subquery.

session_lap_times schema:

```
session_id, int
user_id, int
track_id, int
duration, decimal
```

This is what I've got so far.

```
SELECT 
   session_id
   user_id,
   track_id,
   duration, 
   FIND_IN_SET( duration, 
     (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( duration ORDER BY duration ASC ) FROM 
       (SELECT user_id,track_id,min(duration) 
         FROM session_lap_times GROUP BY user_id,track_id) AS aa WHERE track_id=s1.track_id)
       ) as ranking 
   FROM session_lap_times s1
   WHERE user_id=1
```

It seems like its trying to enforce the group by rules on the parent queries as well.

For reference, this is the error I'm getting: http://imgur.com/a/ILufE

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, the problem is here (broken out for clarity):

```
SELECT user_id,track_id,any_value(duration) 
FROM session_lap_times
GROUP BY user_id
```

The query is probably barfing because track_id is in the select and not in the group by.  That means the subselect doesn't stand on its own and makes the whole thing fail.

Try adding track_id to your group by and adjust from there.

Comment: See my updated query. You must have caught me when I was editing it. Sorry. I wrapped any_value() around track_id. This didnt resolve it anyway :(

Answer (score 0):

You are grouping by user_id but you do not do any aggregation in select or having in the following sub-query

> SELECT 
>                              user_id,any_value(track_id),any_value(duration) 
>                          FROM session_lap_times GROUP BY user_id

You are using GROUP_CONCAT in a wrong context in the following sub-query because you do not group any column in ranking temporary table.

> (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( duration ORDER BY duration ASC ) FROM 
>          (SELECT user_id,track_id,any_value(duration) 
>            FROM session_lap_times GROUP BY user_id,track_id) AS aa WHERE track_id=s1.track_id)
>          ) as ranking

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "You are grouping by user_id but you do not do any aggregation in select or having in the following sub-query". How do I do this aggregation? thanks.

Comment: In that part of the subquery I'm just wanting to return all rows with a distinct user_id, and then also (not distinct) track_id, and min(duration). I've updated the post with my most recent query.

Comment: RE point 2, "GROUP_CONCAT( duration ORDER BY duration ASC )". But I am grouping by "duration"? 

I'm pretty sure the problem is in the first bit you highlighted because if I dont have a subquery in the FROM clause it works as one would expect it to.